# Will this redirect work in the httpd.conf

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Will this redirect work [a-z]* to example.com

ie., I want to redirect anything to example.com

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect anything to example.com, what you probably want is something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]*$ http://www.example.com [R,L]
```

This will redirect ANY request made to the any part of your URL to http://www.example.com.  I.e.,

```
http://mysite.com => http://www.example.com
http://mysite.com/asdasd => http://www.example.com
http://mysite.com/another/test => (not forwarded)
```

Comment: and if I want to redirect example.net to example.com, do I write something like this---------------------------><VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName y.com
    ServerAlias *.y.com
    Redirect permanent / http://x.com/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.  I thought you were only trying to forward requests that matched a pattern.  If you just want to have the entire domain forwarded, joschi's answer is the better one.

Comment: my question stands as it is.  But I got confused with the adding of virtual host in the httpd.conf and the rewriterule. I want to add it to the httpd.conf than to the www directory

Comment: In the case of `RewriteRule`, you can add it inside or outside a `VirtualHost` directive.  Adding it to the `VirtualHost` will only rewrite for requests matching that host.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `RedirectPermanent / http://example.com/` in your Apache httpd configuration should do the trick.